# What parts/tuning should I be using for off road cars?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

In Forza Horizon 2, you spend quite a bit of time off-roading, especially in free-roam.

If I wanted to build a purely offroad car what should I go after. My main questions are in the tires, suspension, and weight aspects. As well as tuning these parts to be the most effective.

So far the only thing I know I *need* is AWD and an engine with enough torque for climbing.

Tires come in, at most, 4 options: stock, street, sport, and race. None of them really point towards "off-road" or even "rally".

Suspension again uses those 4 options, but it affects my ride height and stiffness. Do I want the low ride height and stiffness of Race? or get race then tune it to be "correct"

Weight is pretty binary question, do I want to be lighter or heavier.

I'm looking for the best control and acceleration. Speed isn't *super* important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo Rapitor!

In general, you want to have the car higher and lighter. At least for converting a normal car. It might be a bit harder to do with supercars, because they're already so low, but this should work with most others.

So -

AWD isn't a must if you have enough power, but it's definitely the best option to go with.

For tyres, experiment with street and sport. At least in theory these two options should be your best bet, but game logic might prove me wrong and race might in fact be better. This is something YOU will have to experiment with, because different tyres effect the handling greatly, and you might find one tyre works better for your driving style than others.
EDIT: Go with the widest tyres also ;)

For suspension, get the Race upgrade because you can make the car a lot higher with this option (even though it defaults to a lower setting). Once again you want to experiment with this. Don't go with full height, but raise it up over half way, then lower or raise it as necessary. An overall softer setting is best for offroading, but too soft and the car will become unstable.

You want the car as light as possible, with the frame (roll cage) as tight as possible.

Engine upgrades are at your discretion, but if you install a turbo, try the smaller turbo first. It kicks in at a lower rev range, and as long as the power is getting to the ground, this will help with acceleration. The bigger turbo is more for top end speed.

I hope this helps out. I lost my save so I'm starting again but I had some off road setups that I spent far too long perfecting. Once I get back to where I was in the game I'll set some up again and share them with you, as this is all just going off what I can remember. :)

Gamertag: SS ZARIS

Answer (score 0):

To provide an answer with the changes made in Storm Island, you should also be using Off-road Suspension and Off-road Tyre compound. Both significantly improve performance in off-road sections, with the Off-road suspension allowing for greater ride height and being softer by default, which helps to adsorb the bumps.

Answer (score -2):

I can suggest trying the Ram Runner.. its 2wd but fully upgraded is a dream to drive off road. Also, i haven't touched a setting in tuning the Ram Runner. Good luck

Comment: Cars pre-built for the offroad bracket like the "extreme offroad" are all usually pretty good. My question is that I want to actually make a "normal" car perform better off-road.